# group by two columns based on created column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have a data set like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '11:20', '13:30', '15:20', '17:12', '16:00', '8:20'],
               'item': [coffee, bread, pizza, rice, soup, coffee, bread, pizza, rice, soup]})
```

I want to split the time into 3 meal times breakfast, lunch, dinner. and add it to data

I did it like this

```
df['hour'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
def time_period(hour):
if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
    return 'breakfast'
elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
    return 'lunch'
else:
    return 'dinner'
df['meal'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda x: time_period(x))
```

now I want to groupby the data based on these 3 meals and have an output like this:
[image]

Comment: `df2 = df.groupby([df.meal, df.item]).count()` something like that you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].replace(r'[:]','.',regex=True).astype(float)
df['meal'] = pd.cut(df['time'],bins = [6,11,15,24],labels = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner'])
a = df.groupby(['meal','item']).size()
l = []
for i in np.sort(a.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()):
    l.append(a.loc[i].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'count'}))
b = pd.concat(l,axis=1)
c = [i for i in a.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()*2]
c = np.sort(c)
b.columns = [c,b.columns]
```

Comment: ValueError: 'meal' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: perhaps try without the first two lines of code, as it appears you already have code to get `meal`.

Comment: yes it is true, do you know how can I sort the table based on the breakfast count?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look exactly as your expected output, but it follows the same idea:

```
>>> df.groupby("meal")["item"].value_counts()
meal       item  
breakfast  bread     1
           soup      1
dinner     pizza     2
           rice      2
           bread     1
lunch      coffee    2
           soup      1
```